# Layout issues trying to get ListView to show fixed number of items

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, layout, uwp

In a UWP Project I have a `ListView` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` of `Person` objects. I use a `DataTemplate` to display the `Person` object within the `ListView`. The collection (people) can only contain up to a certain number of people set by `_maxPeopleCount`.

What I would like to happen is for the `ListView` to:

1. Not scroll at all.
2. Show ALL `Person` objects as defined by `_maxPeopleCount`.
3. Show each `Person` objects fully, not partially. That is, show each item so that ListViewItem.Height = (Available Height from ItemsPanel ) / `_maxPeopleCount`.
4. When there are less than `_maxPeopleCount` items to start with still show the added items with there Height as defined in (3).
5. Show the FirstName and LastName of each Person to be as large as possible.

At the moment I can't get my project to do this.

Here is the example code that shows the issue. Simply press the button more than 7 times, as this is the `_maxPeopleCount` in the code. You will see that 7 people do not get shown. Apologies for the awful UI. It's made to show problem with minimal XAML but be similar to my real project.

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    int _personCount = 0;
    int _maxPeopleCount = 7;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _people;

    }

    private void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_people.Count == _maxPeopleCount)
        {
            _people.RemoveAt(_people.Count - 1);
        }
        _personCount += 1;
        _people.Insert(0, new Person($"FirstName {_personCount}", $"LastName {_personCount}"));
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnAddPerson" Click="btnAddPerson_Click" Content="Add Person" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    <ListView BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grdPerson">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

PERSON CLASS:

```
  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
         FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }


    private string _firstName = string.Empty;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string _lastName = string.Empty;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


}
```

Comment: Do you need the ListViewItems to be selectable? Will you need to handle the ItemClick event?

Comment: @DecadeMoon, no the ListViewItems don't need to be selectable and I won't need to handle the ItemClick event. The ListView is purely read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've cracked it! I changed the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `UniformGrid` panel that I got from [here](https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control) . Its a UWP version for the one that WPF has, and as such you can set the number of rows and columns. for my example above, Rows = 7 , Columns = 1.

All I changed after that was to add the following additional `Setter` in the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
```

which fixed the issue of the `ListViewItems` content not being maximized.

Hope this helps others, and cheers to those who replied with help.

Comment: with only this, which I also mentioned in my reply of your forth requirement, you cannot guarantee your third requirement actually, You can have a test based on  my answer.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT,  Using the UniformGrid does give me my 3rd requirement.

Comment: Hello. Would you mind providing an example of this? I'm struggling with this problem. I want to show a fixed number of items in a listview/gridview, but always get partial items when scrolling. Tried a lot of tricks and this solution, but cannot get it to work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Not scroll at all.

For this, you have already done by `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"`.

> Show ALL Person objects as defined by _maxPeopleCount.

Actually you have already bind `_maxPeopleCount` person records to the `ListView`, but restricted by the windows size you cannot see them all. The invisible records do exist there. If you stretch the application windows size to let the height be larger by manually dragging you will see the remaining records. If you want to keep all the records always be shown visible you may need to calculate the `ListViewItem` height by yourself.

> Show each Person objects fully, not partially. That is, show each item so that ListViewItem.Height = (Available Height from ItemsPanel ) / _maxPeopleCount.

In your scenario, the height of `ListViewItem` is calculated automatically since you don't set a fix height for it. As the formula you showed here, we can dynamically bind the height of `ListViewItem` by [`ViewTreeHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243038) class in code behind. Pay attention that windows size change will influence the actual size of the `ListView`, so we also need to resize the `ListViewItem` when applicaiton window size changed. When the height of `ListViewItem` is setting to  less than `44`, it will not take effects since the default `MinHeight` of [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) is `44`, which need to reset. More settings for implementing this requirement please reference the demo below.

> When there are less than _maxPeopleCount items to start with still show the added items with there Height as defined in (3).

After calulated, all the `ListViewItem` will have the same height.

> Show the FirstName and LastName of each Person to be as large as possible.

For this you have `<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>` to stretch the horizontal content, please also stretch the vertical content by `<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>`. And `padding` of `ListviewItem` need to be set to `0`.

Updated code as follows which can meet all your above requirements now.

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="gridroot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnAddPerson" Click="btnAddPerson_Click" Content="Add Person" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listperson"  BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grdPerson" Loaded="grdPerson_Loaded" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    int _personCount = 0;
    int _maxPeopleCount = 7;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _people;
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
    } 
    public void resize()
    { 
        var listpersonheight = listperson.ActualHeight; 
        IEnumerable<ListViewItem> items = FindVisualChildren<ListViewItem>(listperson);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
            {
                item.Height = (listpersonheight - 10) / _maxPeopleCount;// BorderThickness size need to be minus.
                item.Width = listperson.ActualWidth - 10; //Width also need resize.
            }
        }
    }
    private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        resize();
    }
    private void grdPerson_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resize();
    }
    private void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (_people.Count == _maxPeopleCount)
        {
            _people.RemoveAt(_people.Count - 1);
        }
        _personCount += 1; 
        _people.Insert(0, new Person($"FirstName {_personCount}", $"LastName {_personCount}")); 
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunteen, thanks for your response. I the meantime I've found an alternative solution that works that I've posted below.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own Panel, it's quite easy to do. Here's a UniformStackPanel I wrote which works like a StackPanel except it will stretch each item to fill the available space (regardless of how many items it has).

```
public class UniformStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var childSize = Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ?
            new Size(availableSize.Width / Children.Count, availableSize.Height) :
            new Size(availableSize.Width, availableSize.Height / Children.Count);

        double alongAxis = 0;
        double crossAxis = 0;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(childSize);

            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                alongAxis += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                crossAxis = Math.Max(crossAxis, child.DesiredSize.Height);
            }
            else
            {
                alongAxis += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                crossAxis = Math.Max(crossAxis, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            }
        }

        return Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ?
            new Size(alongAxis, crossAxis) :
            new Size(crossAxis, alongAxis);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var childSize = Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ?
            new Size(finalSize.Width / Children.Count, finalSize.Height) :
            new Size(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height / Children.Count);

        double alongAxis = 0;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                child.Arrange(new Rect(alongAxis, 0, childSize.Width, childSize.Height));
                alongAxis += childSize.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                child.Arrange(new Rect(0, alongAxis, childSize.Width, childSize.Height));
                alongAxis += childSize.Height;
            }
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Use it with an ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:UniformStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="RoyalBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Crimson" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Decade Moon , thanks for the suggestion. I ended up thinking along similar lines, but used a UniformGrid panel. See my answer post. Appreciate the help.